# Need to get 1st 5 or 6 character after ":" in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I need to get all the data before ":" in my sql. Below is the example of my data

```
1234:london
12344:idea get 
123456:thanks dublin
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Substring_index()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function. Since you want to get the substring before the **first** occurence of `:`, we set `count` (third parameter in the function) as **1**:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`data`, ':', 1) as string_before_colon;
```

[**Details:**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,delim,count)
```

> Returns the substring from string str **before** count occurrences of the
>   delimiter delim. If count is positive, everything to the left of the
>   final delimiter (counting from the left) is returned. If count is
>   negative, everything to the right of the final delimiter (counting
>   from the right) is returned. **SUBSTRING_INDEX() performs a
>   case-sensitive match when searching for delim**.

Answer (score 0):

use SUBSTRING_INDEX()

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(data, ":", 1);
```